# tomato-substitute for sausage and spaghetti squash?

Tags: substitutions, tomatoes, sausages, squash

I just got diagnosed with an autoimmune disorder and have to avoid both grains and tomatoes. I was wondering if there is a way to substitute tomatoes to create a nice sauce that would go well with sausages and spaghetti squash?

If a non-tomato sauce isn't feasible, how does one make the dish not dry without a sauce? I can have (cooked) alcohol-based sauces. Is there a particular alcoholic drink that could be a good base for a sauce for sweet pork sausage and spaghetti squash?

Comment: This question is essentially a recipe request, so it's likely to get closed because such questions (while they are certainly good and interesting) aren't a good fit for this site. My personal recommendation would be to Google 'Italian sauces without tomato' which turns up plenty of results (since you seemed to want an Italian vibe).

Comment: Yep - tons of sauces out there, most don't contain tomato. If you can find it, I recommend the [Silver Spoon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/136599.The_Silver_Spoon), which has a whole section on sauces.

Comment: Hi Isabella, sorry to hear about your condition. Since no sauce will taste like tomato sauce, this reads like a request for a different sauce that pairs well with your food, and that's how answers have interpreted it so far. Sadly, our site cannot deal with this random kind of answers, as there is no objectively best pairing. So this kind of question is off topic. The upside is that, since any good combination tastes well to somebody, you can try whatever you want and discover new things you like.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with butter, salt and pepper. That's my favorite way to eat spaghetti squash!

Answer (score 0):

I use Basil based Pesto with my Spaghetti Squash/Sausage.